# Contract verification failure in corda Hello World pt 2

Tags: kotlin, corda

I'm following the tutorial in [corda tutorial pt 2](https://docs.corda.net/tut-two-party-flow.html) using kotlin.  Everytime I try to start a new flow via the CRaSH shell in PartyA using the next command:

```
start IOUFlow iouValue: 30, otherParty: "C=US, L=New York, O=PartyB"
```

I get a Contract Verification Failure:

```
Done    
Contract verification failed: List has more than one element., contract: com.template.IOUContract@7c109db7, transaction: D08920023D788F80F289527BD9C27BCD54B7DAC6C53866BFA7B90B23E0E4749B
```

IOUFlow class:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class IOUFlow(val iouValue: Int,
              val otherParty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]
        val outputState = IOUState(iouValue, ourIdentity, otherParty)
        val outputContract = IOUContract::class.jvmName
        val outputContractAndState = StateAndContract(outputState, outputContract)
        val cmd = Command(IOUContract.Create(), listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey, otherParty.owningKey))

        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
                .addOutputState(outputState, TEMPLATE_CONTRACT_ID)
                .addCommand(cmd)

        txBuilder.withItems(outputContractAndState, cmd)
        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)
        val signedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)
        val otherpartySession = initiateFlow(otherParty)
        val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(signedTx, listOf(otherpartySession), CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()))
        subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx))
    }
}
```

I've tried modifying App.kt to deal with this problem without luck.  Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're adding the command and output to the transaction twice:

```
val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
    .addOutputState(outputState, TEMPLATE_CONTRACT_ID)
    .addCommand(cmd)

txBuilder.withItems(outputContractAndState, cmd)
```

This causes the contract verification to fail, as you have two outputs instead of one.

Comment: Thanks Joel, removing duplicated `cmd` and `outputState` made the trick.